# ASIO (C++ 11) strand.post causes segmentation fault when using private member function

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, callback, boost-asio

I'm learning to use the ASIO library and I am trying to start a custom handler after an asynchronous read.

```
void myConnection::start()
{
    conSocket.async_read_some(asio::buffer(conIOBuf),
        [this](const std::error_code error, std::size_t length)
        {
            std::cout << "LOG: Starting Callback\n";
            myQStrand.post(
                [this, &error]
                {
                    pushToMyQ(privateQ, error);
                });
        });
}
```

I've used gdb to debug the executable, however when I run it I get a segmentation fault at the pushToMyQ line in the code. I have checked both error and privateQ, they both have valid addresses and when their member functions are called they work.

myConnection is a child from a purely virtual parent class to keep the naming and some of the accessors constant between another class. privateQ is held by a manager class that passes the queue by reference to myConnection which holds it as a private member.

What could be causing the segmentation fault to happen in the lambda at the line where pushToMyQ is being executed?

Comment: This question needs a [mcve]. But I suspect you have a lifetime issue with one of the objects referred to in the call, perhaps `myQStrand` or `privateQ`. Now that I think of it, `error` is probably out of scope by the time your inner lambda is called.

Comment: How can I ensure that it keeps stays in scope?

Comment: If `error` is the only problem, you could probably capture it by value instead of by reference. It may not be the only problem, though. Can't tell with what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

You pass a reference to a local (`error`) to an asynchronous task. That's no good.

The asynchronous task also keeps a copy of `this`, which might not live at the time the asynchronous task is executed (we can't know because the surrounding code is not shown)